# Image mouseover follow cursor position with multiple images

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I want to know how to get the image mouseover effect on multiple images with different delays between the images.

Here is what i am looking for: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/45859.html

Comment: Just view the source of that page, and you'll find out.

Comment: The effect you're looking for is 'parallax'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Remus said, the effect you're looking for is 'parallax'. But because parallax gives you so much results, with all different ways of using it. I will point you in the right direction. The jQuery plugin, jParallax is what you are looking for. (demo: http://stephband.info/jparallax/demos/index.html) and you can download it here: http://stephband.info/jparallax/